Noise when letting off the accelerator subaru legacy
2018 Subaru Legacy- have a slight noise/rattle when I let off on the accelerator. It happens every single time too. The transmission seems to have no issues and we just replaced the front hubs, all tires and got an alignment.  Noise is coming from rear.

Can you make the sound happen when parked? If so, it's worth quickly checking the muffler and connected exhaust bits. I like to have a helper work the gas pedal while I poke various exhaust piping with an old broomstick. When you find the right bit, a little pressure will usually change / stop the noise.

no, we can't make the noise while parked, it just when the car is moving.  The tires and alignment were done about 2 weeks ago and the noise just appeared a few days ago.  I thought it might be the rear hubs as we replaced the front ones?

Okay, that's useful background information. Good luck!

I've had similar on my Subaru.  If the shock absorbers/steering knuckles/related parts were not bolted up to the torque specification after work was done on the car, I could hear a noise. Hopefully that is all it is, even an alignment shop can forget to do this.
A few questions please; How long does the noise last for?  Is the noise metallic sounding?  Is it a clunk or rotation type noise?  If rotation is the frequency of the noise perhaps related or change with the speed of the engine or vehicle speed?  Does it happen with the engine warmed up and not?
As Pfeldman suggested it could just be lug nuts uneven or there could be rattle on the catalytic converter shields or exhaust parts which is quite common.  Also, could be the long driveshaft between the transmission and rear diff - check for any looseness with the engine cold.

Did this noise only appear after the hub service?
Logically, it would be best to go straight for the latest change.
What you describe though, could be many things. Last time someone described your symptoms to me, it was just loose lug nuts.
If you can, lift the rear end and feel for any looseness in the wheels. Also check that wheels are torqued to spec.

We will check this tonight and yes the noise started after the hub service, although we replaced the front hubs and not the rear. It is an AWD vehicle.
